Selecting last instance of a column, but comparing different column with CASE
I am expecting 3 columns: the Order number from TOrder, the last instance (max) OrderEvent ID, and I want to apply case/when to another column (ordereventtypeid).
The order number and last instance works. However, I have been unable to get the third column working. Essentially, I want to pull the last instance of OrderEventId for each OrderId, but then apply CASE/WHEN to that row.  What is happening below is that is returning "T&R" delay for all of them rather than only those where the last OrderEventTypeID is "107".
SELECT 
   TOrder.OrderNumber
   ,(SELECT MAX (OrderEventID) FROM TOrderEvent
    WHERE TOrderEvent.OrderID = TOrder.OrderID
    ) AS 'Delay SubQ'
   ,CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT MAX (OrderEventID) FROM TOrderEvent
                     WHERE TOrderEvent.OrderID = TOrder.OrderID
                       AND TOrderEvent.OrderEventTypeID IN (107)) 
            THEN 'T&R Delay'
            ELSE ''
    END AS 'Delay Case'
FROM 
    TOrder
WHERE 
    TOrder.CustomerId IN (14758, 25167)
    AND TOrder.OrderDate >= '1/1/2024'
    AND TOrder.OrderStatusID NOT IN (1206, 1208)

I have tried using subqueries, joins, etc.  When joining TOrderEvent and using MAX ON TOrderEvent.OrderEventID, I get a row for each ordereventid rather than a single row for each orderid with only the last instance of the ordereventid.
I am using SSMS 19.0.20209 with Azure hosted SQL as a service.

Can you provide sample table contents & expected query results?

Please read How to make a good example and also tag the RDBMS you use.

@ScottHunter Sure, is this acceptable?
TOrder:
OrderNumber
OrderId – can be joined to TOrderEvent.OrderID (this is how they relate)
TOrderEvent:
OrderId – relationship to TOrder
OrderEventId – auto-incrementing id number (PK).  This is how unique rows are identified of Events related to Orders.
OrderEventTypeID – a numeric classification of the Event.  This is where I’m trying to apply CASE, i.e. if the last OrderEventId related to the order has an OrderEventTypeID  “107” then return “T&R Delay”

That is, at best, a description of table schema, not an example of its contents.

Use row_number in a subquery. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@JonasMetzler Hello, I'm not sure what else you want me to do.  The code/explanation is formatted per my interpretation of your link. I also took this from a 30+ field query down to 3 that are all required in the relational aspects.  It's as minimal as possible to execute a query while retaining relationship requirements.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Side note, don't use single quotes (') for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They have some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you must delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets ([]), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (").

Please add details to your question, not comments. Then you can use formatted code, etc

As they say in Hollywood, show don't tell. Why not post a few rows of data in table format and the expected result

Try this
SELECT 
    TOrder.OrderNumber,
    oe.MaxOrderEventID AS [Delay SubQ],
    CASE 
        WHEN oe.OrderEventTypeID = 107 THEN 'T&R Delay'
        ELSE ''
    END AS [Delay Case]
FROM 
    TOrder
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            TOrderEvent.OrderEventID AS MaxOrderEventID,
            TOrderEvent.OrderEventTypeID
        FROM 
            TOrderEvent
        WHERE 
            TOrderEvent.OrderID = TOrder.OrderID
        ORDER BY 
            TOrderEvent.OrderEventID DESC
    ) oe
WHERE 
    TOrder.CustomerId IN (14758, 25167)
    AND TOrder.OrderDate >= '2024-01-01'
    AND TOrder.OrderStatusID NOT IN (1206, 1208);


I'm glad I could help! to understand  this better read about "CROSS APPLY"

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
